# Find Parse username using client Key or App ID for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

> I forgot email address registered with parse account what I have is
>   the Application ID and client Key. Is there any way to find out the 
>   username I used register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no automated way to do this.

I'm sure your use case is legitimate, however a hacker could easily obtain the Application ID and Client Key through a number of means. (These values can be exposed by examining an API, or for example the javascript key + application ID can be found simply by examining the source code on a website).

If a person with malicious intentions were able to gain an email from the (application id + client key), they would then only need to guess the password, for full access to the Parse account.

Assuming your means are legitimate you could:

1. Login to your existing Parse.com accounts and see if the Parse app is there. Surely you can't have signed up with that many addresses.
2. Login to all your email accounts and search for "parse.com", to find what account you signed up with.
3. If you have signed up with a credit card with Parse, you may be able to contact them, and identify yourself via your credit card details. (I doubt this would work though, as credit card details can be easily compromised these days).

Comment: I found the email account used. I followed second procedure. (y)

Comment: @hara Awesome! Shame there wasn't a simpler way. Hopefully you didn't have too many email accounts, or it wasn't another staff member's account who wasn't in on the weekend!